# How can I set a dark mode in TeXnicCenter?

Tags: texniccenter

I just started using TeXnicCenter, and I would really enjoy it more if its background was dark, i.e. if it had a dark theme. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you tried the path: `tools→ options → text format → colors`? I have not used TeXnicCenter because it is an old editor. It was my preferite editor.

Comment: I just did. And it worked! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the editor window to a dark theme with ***Tools>Options>Text Format>Color***. There is a *Dark* theme and a *Dark High Contrast* theme, as well as some customizable options.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to the interface you can't do much about it. Just check ***View>Application Look>Office 2007>Black***, but it's quite far from ***dark mode***. For the editor panel you can change colors in ***Tools>Option>Text Format***. There you can change scheme to dark and then customize colors whatever you want.